# Google Analytics data (timeOnPage & searchStartPage) in BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

We're migrating from the Google Analytics API to BigQuery API.

In the GA API, I can request ga:timeOnPage and ga:searchStartPage, but is this possible in BigQuery (because of the fact that this includes comparing with a previous/future hit)?

If so, how can I set up my query?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

- totals.timeOnScreen
- hits.page.pagePath

You will use `hits.page.pagePath` when you have `hits.page.searchKeyword` value. This will be your search results page.

In the `hits` you have a list of events, and you have also access to `hits.hitNumber`. And based on the hit number -1 position, you can obtain the search start page. Which is the page prior to the results page.

Check out the exported schema https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

Comment: Are you sure about totals.timeOnScreen? I only get "null" values and one might think that the timeOnScreen only refers to mobile hits. Regarding the searchStartPage, I guess it's not possible to retrieve the searchStartPage in a single query? Or can I somehow use subqueries in this case?

Comment: You should get in contact with the support to clarify this. Usually schema outputs need adjustments in the backend.